# VBA Unable to get StDev property of Worksheet Class

Tags: vba, runtime-error, worksheet-function

I'm trying to run a macro that goes through a data sheet and calculates the standard deviation of columns G through R. Every time I run the program, I get a Runtime 1004 error saying that it can't get the StDev property of the WorksheetFunction Class. I didn't have this error when I ran it about 2 weeks ago, so I don't know what to do. Here's the section of the code where the error occurs at.

```
For i = 1 To lastFilledRow

    standardDeviationT = WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range("G" + CStr(i) + ":R" + CStr(i)))
    Range("AB" & CStr(i)) = standardDeviationT

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

The StDev function requires at least two numbers to be passed. If your Range only has 0 or 1 values then the function will fail and fire the error. To make sure you are passing at least 2, I recommend calling Count first:

```
For i = 1 To 100
    If WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("G" + CStr(i) + ":R" + CStr(i))) >= 2 Then
        standardDeviationT = WorksheetFunction.StDev(Range("G" + CStr(i) + ":R" + CStr(i)))
        Range("AB" & CStr(i)) = standardDeviationT
    End If
Next i
```

Also, if you are using modern Excel I.E 2010, you may want to consider switching to using StDev_S, as Micorsoft recommends it. Here is an exert from the [MSDN on StDev](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839479.aspx).

> This function has been replaced with one or more new functions that
>   may provide improved accuracy and whose names better reflect their
>   usage. This function is still available for compatibility with earlier
>   versions of Excel. However, if backward compatibility is not required,
>   you should consider using the new functions from now on, because they
>   more accurately describe their functionality.
>
> For more information about the new function, see the [StDev_S](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835583.aspx) method.